# Is there a suffix in "masquerade"?

Tags: suffixes

Is there a suffix in *masquerade*?

in *masquerade*, *masque* means mask, so is *-rade* or *-ade* its suffix?

*-ade* is a suffix in *lemonade* and *blockade*, meaning "product".

Note: I have searched it in etymonline, but couldn't find my answer

Comment: The word is ***Suffix***, not "postfix". And, yes, _-ade_ is a suffix. But it's not an English suffix; it's a French suffix, and the whole word _masquerade_ was borrowed from French, as you can tell by its spelling. Furthermore, it's a [derivational suffix](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Derivation-Inflection.pdf), and derivational affixes are all irregular and don't have much meaning. So, it doesn't help to recognize something as being a suffix when it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Thanks. (1) So its suffix is -ade. why is there a r in front it? (2) is the linked pdf file an excerpt from a book?

Comment: (1) Probably because the root ends in /r/. (2) No. It's a handout from an Intro Ling class. There are more available.

Comment: (1) *masque* doesn't end with r, does it?

Comment: No, but infinitives do in French, and this is from a verb root. I mentioned that it wasn't an English suffix, right?

Answer (score 3):

The word apparently comes from Spanish *máscara* "mask", which according to most scholars comes from Arabic *sakhira* "to ridicule", so says the Oxford English Dictionary. Some scholars rather believe it comes from a Germanic root. (Perhaps surprisingly, there is less consensus about the English word *mask*: it may come from the same Arabic root, or from a different Latin root derived from a Germanic root, or from a combination of both.)

The Spanish suffix *-(a)da* means something like "abstract noun related to x", and Spanish *mascarada* means "masquerade". English has *-e* because it was borrowed through French, in which language feminine *-a* is regularly converted into *-a*. The Spanish suffix comes from Latin *-(a)ta*, the feminine past participle.